# Is there a way to prevent a 3rd party JS code located in the <head> from taking down a site if not available?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I'm building a feature which require web publishers to put a JS code snippet in the  section of a page in order for it to work. This code includes a call to an external (and dynamically generated) JS file from a remote server. The file cannot be cached so putting it on a CDN isn't an option.

What I'm worried about is that if there will ever be a problem with the remote server which will make the remote file unreachable, it can take down the page in which the code is included (potentially the entire site as the code suppose to be included site-wide).

Is there a way to make sure that no matter what, the availability of the remote file will never affect the availability of the page in which the code is included?

-edit-
The resources in the remote file need to be available before the HTML of the page starts to render. Loading the code asynchronously isn't an option.

Comment: Can you please include the snippet? More detail needed.

Comment: For simplicity purposes, lets assume this is the code: <script src="somefile.js?var=123"></script>

Answer (score 1):

You could specify `async=true` which will not "block" your page from resuming loading other resources. Otherwise it'll halt at that script, though it may vary depending on how each browser handles stalling script elements.

Note: The support of the async attribute varies - modern browsers circa 2014 will understand it but if you need to support legacy browsers you may need to look for an alternative solution ( which you can see @ the link referenced ).

More details @ https://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/

Comment: The thing is that I need the resources of the file to be available before the HTML starts to render. Doesn't putting async beats this objective?